# How can I get all comments from a table MySQL

Tags: mysql, count, comments

Well I want to count and display comments of my table (stories). Its structure is something like that:

```
id | type    | post        | parent

1  | story   | bla bla bla | 0  

2  | comment | text...     | 1  

3  | comment | text...     | 1 

4  | comment | text...     | 3 

5  | comment | other...    | 1
```

And as you can see, all the information is into one table.

For example, in this case I need to show the 'story' and show how much comments it has.

And I have to list its hierachy.

Something such this:

```
ID. 1 - bla bla bla

Comments

|--ID. 2 text...

|--ID. 3 text...

...|--ID. 4. text.. (comment of ID 3)

|--ID. 5 other..
```

I know how to list the story and all comments that it has when its ID is equals to the story. But I have no idea what I need to do to show and count other ones which has no extend from main story.

What would be the best way to do that?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this
[sqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a6a8/10/0)

```
SELECT root.id as rootid,
       root.type as roottype,
       root.post as rootpost,
       child.id as childid,
       child.type as childtype,
       child.post as childpost,
       NULL as grandchildid,
       NULL as grandchildtype,
       NULL as grandchildpost
FROM stories as root
INNER JOIN stories as child ON child.parent = root.id
WHERE root.parent = 0
  AND root.id = 1
UNION
SELECT root.id as rootid,
       root.type as roottype,
       root.post as rootpost,
       child.id as childid,
       child.type as childtype,
       child.post as childpost,
       grandchild.id as grandchildid,
       grandchild.type as grandchildtype,
       grandchild.post as grandchildpost
FROM stories as root
INNER JOIN stories as child ON child.parent = root.id
INNER JOIN stories as grandchild ON grandchild.parent = child.id
WHERE root.parent = 0
  AND root.id = 1
ORDER BY childid,grandchildid
```

then if you wanted some output that looked something like what you have given above in your question you could do something like in this ([sqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a6a8/12/0))

```
SELECT IF(grandchildid IS NULL,
      CONCAT("--ID. ",childid," ",childpost),
      CONCAT("...--ID. ",grandchildid," ",grandchildpost,"(comment of ID ",childid,")")
      ) as result
FROM
(
SELECT root.id as rootid,
       root.type as roottype,
       root.post as rootpost,
       child.id as childid,
       child.type as childtype,
       child.post as childpost,
       NULL as grandchildid,
       NULL as grandchildtype,
       NULL as grandchildpost
FROM stories as root
INNER JOIN stories as child ON child.parent = root.id
WHERE root.parent = 0
  AND root.id = 1
UNION
SELECT root.id as rootid,
       root.type as roottype,
       root.post as rootpost,
       child.id as childid,
       child.type as childtype,
       child.post as childpost,
       grandchild.id as grandchildid,
       grandchild.type as grandchildtype,
       grandchild.post as grandchildpost
FROM stories as root
INNER JOIN stories as child ON child.parent = root.id
INNER JOIN stories as grandchild ON grandchild.parent = child.id
WHERE root.parent = 0
  AND root.id = 1
ORDER BY childid,grandchildid
)T1
```

If you're gonna allow multiple levels deep, you can create a function like this [sqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/723936/4/0)

```
CREATE FUNCTION getRootId(in_id int) returns int
BEGIN
   DECLARE _parent int;
   DECLARE _id int;
   SET _parent = in_id;
   SET _id = in_id;
   WHILE (_parent != 0) DO
      SELECT id,parent into _id,_parent
      FROM stories WHERE id = _parent;
   END WHILE;
   RETURN _id;
END//
```

and then use it to get all comments that share the root id like below

```
SELECT parent.id as parentId,
   parent.type as parentType,
   parent.post as parentPost,
   child.id as childId,
   child.type as childType,
   child.post as childPost,
   getRootId(child.id) as rootId
FROM stories parent
INNER JOIN stories child ON (child.parent = parent.id)
WHERE getRootId(child.id) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that query works for me, but it is prepared only for 3 deep levels, if I reply the last grandchildpost this query never going to show and count it. That's my problem, I don't know what I have to do to resolve it with SQL.

If there no way, I'm going to resolve it with my programming language, but this will be my last option.

Comment: check bottom of my answer I have created a function to recursively grab the rootId, so you can grab all comments that share the same rootId